# Invoke intellij code formatter programmatically on java files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How can I programmatically invoke intellij's java source code formatter on an arbitrary source file on disk?

I don't mind writing a plugin to do this but if there is a way to invoke the formatter from command line that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can check in with IntelliJ as you *pay* for software, API help is normally provided by the company where you let your money.

Comment: You open the file in IntelliJ, make sure that IntelliJ can identify it as a Java file, then perform the "format code" option (CTRL + ALT + L or Command + Option + L).  The key here is that IntelliJ needs to be aware that it is a source file.  I doubt that this functionality is exposed in an accessible API, nor would it make sense to - IntelliJ has a peculiar setup when it comes to its code style interface.

Comment: Consider something made for the purpose, like Jalopy - https://github.com/notzippy/JALOPY2-MAIN

Comment: There was a video on "Upsource" that I remember which explains the core api, it might be useful to you.

Comment: Intellij already provides that for you, check:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the "Reformat code" function out of IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805960/how-to-get-the-reformat-code-function-out-of-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing my own plugin which is available on [github](https://github.com/ajaykumarns/intellij-fmt). Note that it might need some more fine tuning